# XMLPATH - can't get value from xml

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

```
            <report>
            <document>
            <content>
            <container flag="SEPARATE">
                <relationship>CONTAINS</relationship>
                <concept>
                    <value>T9900-01</value>
                    <scheme>
                        <designator>99GEMS</designator>
                    </scheme>
                    <meaning>User-defined concepts</meaning>
                </concept>
                <container flag="SEPARATE">
                    <relationship>CONTAINS</relationship>
                    <concept>
                        <value>T9900-02</value>
                        <scheme>
                            <designator>99GEMS</designator>
                        </scheme>
                        <meaning>Measurement</meaning>
                    </concept>
                    <text>
                        <relationship>HAS CONCEPT MOD</relationship>
                        <concept>
                            <value>T9900-04</value>
                            <scheme>
                                <designator>99GEMS</designator>
                            </scheme>
                            <meaning>Label</meaning>
                        </concept>
                        <value>IVC Insp</value>
                    </text>
                    <code>
                        <relationship>HAS CONCEPT MOD</relationship>
                        <concept>
                            <value>G-0373</value>
                            <scheme>
                                <designator>SRT</designator>
                            </scheme>
                            <meaning>Image Mode</meaning>
                        </concept>
                        <value>G-03A2</value>
                        <scheme>
                            <designator>SRT</designator>
                        </scheme>
                        <meaning>2D mode</meaning>
                    </code>
                    <num>
                        <relationship>CONTAINS</relationship>
                        <concept>
                            <value>121206</value>
                            <scheme>
                                <designator>DCM</designator>
                            </scheme>
                            <meaning>Distance</meaning>
                        </concept>
                        <code>
                            <relationship>HAS CONCEPT MOD</relationship>
                            <concept>
                                <value>121401</value>
                                <scheme>
                                    <designator>DCM</designator>
                                </scheme>
                                <meaning>Derivation</meaning>
                            </concept>
                            <value>R-00317</value>
                            <scheme>
                                <designator>SRT</designator>
                            </scheme>
                            <meaning>Mean</meaning>
                        </code>
                        <code>
                            <relationship>HAS PROPERTIES</relationship>
                            <concept>
                                <value>121404</value>
                                <scheme>
                                    <designator>DCM</designator>
                                </scheme>
                                <meaning>Selection Status</meaning>
                            </concept>
                            <value>121412</value>
                            <scheme>
                                <designator>DCM</designator>
                            </scheme>
                            <meaning>Mean value chosen</meaning>
                        </code>
                        <value>**0.81897100540927**</value>
                        <unit>
                            <value>cm</value>
                            <scheme>
                                <designator>UCUM</designator>
                            </scheme>
                            <meaning>centimeter</meaning>
                        </unit>
                    </num>
                    <num>
                        <relationship>CONTAINS</relationship>
                        <concept>
                            <value>121206</value>
                            <scheme>
                                <designator>DCM</designator>
                            </scheme>
                            <meaning>Distance</meaning>
                        </concept>
                        <value>0.81897100540927</value>
                        <unit>
                            <value>cm</value>
                            <scheme>
                                <designator>UCUM</designator>
                            </scheme>
                            <meaning>centimeter</meaning>
                        </unit>
                    </num>
                </container>
            </container>        
            </content>
            </document>
            </report>
```

I have this xml, and I'm trying to create XMLPATH to get out the value 0.81897100540927

IF I use:

> report/document/content/container/container[concept[@codValue='T9900-01' and @codScheme='99GEMS']]/container[concept[@codValue='T9900-02' and @codScheme='99GEMS']and code/value[@codValue='G-03A2' and @codScheme='SRT']]/num[concept[@codValue='121206' and @codScheme='DCM'] and code/value[@codValue='121412' and @codScheme='DCM']][1]/value

then I'm getting the right value, but I'm having problem with getting all the other values which are in other containers and the only thing that is different is in /text/value-> "IVC Insp" (others have AT, Ae arcos.,..).

So I tried:

> report/document/content/container/container[concept[@codValue='T9900-01' and @codScheme='99GEMS']]/container[concept[@codValue='T9900-02' and @codScheme='99GEMS']and text/value[@codValue='IVC insp']]/num[concept[@codValue='121206' and @codScheme='DCM'] and code/value[@codValue='121412' and @codScheme='DCM']][1]/value

but doesn't work.

Comment: Your question is unclear; what **exactly** is your desired output?

Comment: I need to extract this number <value>0.81897100540927</value>, but condition in xmlpath must be based on text/value wich is "IVC insp"

Comment: But the container which meets this condition has 15 different values. What makes this particular value the target? Is it the size, the position in the list of values?

Comment: Its simply becuse this number its the obtained measurement  in medical reports which i need to extract from xml. I dont know how to tell otherwise. This xml is 46 pages long, i managed extract 3/4 of values, but this container is somehow different, because it contains text node, and in text node its specified which measurement its gonna be in value below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about your actual document, but strictly based on your xml above, the only thing I can see about the target that  makes it unique, is that it is in a `<container>` that has, among its children, a `<value>` with the text `IVC Insp`; that happens twice, but the `<container>` with the target (unlike the other one) also has `<num>` child, which itself has a `<code>` child. The target is in the `<value>` child of that `<num>`. So, with all that, the target (again, in your xml above) can be selected with the following xpath expression:

```
//container[//value['IVC Insp']]/num[code]/value
```

output:

> 0.81897100540927

Comment: In Eclipse I get with your xmlpath next result: <value>31.7</value><value>42.2</value><value>49.4</value><value>57</value><value>56.1</value><value>54.9</value><value>54.9</value><value>54.9</value><value>55.3</value><value>55.3</value><value>54.9</value><value>54.9</value><value>53.7</value><value>52.8</value><value>51.1</value><value>49.4</value><value>45.6</value><value>41.7</value><value>34.2</value><value>22.3</value><value>65.4</value><value>3290</value><value>126000</value>,...

Comment: @Bepohnka - Those values don't appear in the XML above. Strictly based on your question, the xpath expression works. If you have more `<report>`s with different characteristics, things may change. It's impossible to tell without seeing the full XML, which I imagine is very long.